# how to cache favicon javascript

Tags: javascript, caching, favicon

I'm trying to cache my favicon image just like any other image, but I'm not seeing it in the cache, nor getting my confirmation console.log, nor seeing it when I disconnect from the internet (basically it is not caching).

I want to cache it so I can access it offline, so I can dynamically change the icon if the internet disconnects.

My html:

```
<link id="favicon" rel="icon" type="image/png" src="assets/favicon-red-16x16.ico.png">
```

My js:

```
// cache images
function preloadImages(array) {
    if (!preloadImages.list) {
        preloadImages.list = [];
    }
    var list = preloadImages.list;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        console.log('caching image...')
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            console.log('image cached')
            var index = list.indexOf(this);
            if (index !== -1) {
                // remove image from the array once it's loaded
                // for memory consumption reasons
                list.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
        list.src = array[i];
    }
}
preloadImages(["../assets/favicon-green-16x16.ico.png", "../assets/favicon-red-16x16.ico.png"]);
```

question: Is it possible to cache the favicon client side? Is there another way to store it locally?

if i convert to base64 how do I store and grab it from local storage?

ps. using Chrome latest

***<___ UPDATE ___>***

Though the question is technically answered, How can I do this two store 2 (more than one) base64 image? I can't figure out how to draw 2 onto a canvas or 2 canvases.

Comment: Why do you try to cache images by yourself? This is a task for the web browser.

Comment: You can try converting image to base64 and storing it in the localStorage of the browser.

Comment: @lilezek because it is a requirement for this application, if it goes offline I want to be able to change the icon to a red dot to signal disconnect to the user even if they aren't on the page

Comment: @HarunDilukaHeshan how would I do that? and once it's encoded how would I call it from the cache?

Comment: You can directly use base64 encoded string on src attributes of the link to display the favicon.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html

Comment: So you are trying to develop an offline application. That should appear in your questions. You are trying to set up manually a favicon, not really trying to cache things.

Comment: i am trying to cache things, let me update my q. If my question is how to cache something, I shouldn't have to specify why, it could be for no reason at all, it's just a question

Comment: I disagree. My question has nothing to do with changing the favicon, I already can do that, my question is how to store the favicon in the cache for offline  access.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code pal.
You can hide iconImage img element. The other img tag i have used, is for testing only, so you can remove it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link id="favicon" rel="icon" href="img_the_scream.jpg" />
<body>

<img id="iconImage"  src="img_the_scream.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="220" height="277">
<br />
<img id="img" width="220" height="277"/>
<script>

function onLoadHandler() {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("iconImage");
    var base64Image = localStorage.getItem("lsFavicon");
    var favicon = document.getElementById("favicon");
    var img2 = document.getElementById("img");

    if (base64Image == null && document.navigator.onLine) {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        base64Image = canvas.toDataURL();
        localStorage.setItem("lsFavicon", base64Image);
        favicon.setAttribute("href", base64Image);
    }
    else if (base64Image != null) {
        favicon.setAttribute("href", base64Image);
        img2.setAttribute("src", base64Image);
    }
}

window.onload = onLoadHandler;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey thanks for actually trying to answer my question, I'll give it a shot, this looks like a good solution. I'll get back to you once I have tried it

Comment: This worked great! just one question, how do I do this for two separate favicons? I guess I'm missing the concept for setting one, so I can't seem to repeat it for two icon images